# How to construct cyclic and self dual code (12,4)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, cryptography, coding-theory

Question is:

Construct cyclic and self dual code (12,4). Both codes has 4 bits for data and 12 bits for codeword. Construct generation matrix for both codes. Prove that both codes are equal.

I am stuck on how to start solving this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd add the label ''coding-theory''.

Comment: Something does not add up? The dimension of a self-dual code is always half the length, so I would expect 6 bits of data, and $4$ might be the minimum distance?? Did you mean *self-orthogonal* instead of self-dual?